# Multiple layout UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a UserControl that manages a lot of editable information (like text-boxes). Now I need to make a version of this control that has a different layout (from horizontal to vertical). I can expose the control, like this:

```
public TextBox MyText
{
    get { return myText; }
    set { myText = value; }
}
```

I can now manually change the location and size, but this does not give me a visual reposition of them at design time.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: "...does not give me a visual reposition of them at design time". What do you mean by that sentence? If you change the location manually, why doesn't it display that?
In general, I do not really understand the question. Try to be more specific. Furthermore, you should tell us what kind of UI you are using: WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Perhaps my situation better explains this question:

In Windows Forms, I built a custom control containing a couple of buttons and a text field. But I want two versions of this custom control: one with the buttons on the right of the text field, and one with the buttons on the left of the text field. Different layouts, but the same behavior. Note that the intent is NOT for I18N or RTL layout.

Is there a way to build an "abstract" parent control from which the two layouts can inherit?